# Does python have something similar to C#'s AsyncLocal?

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, asynchronous

I guess this is a one-liner question: with C# you can use [`AsyncLocal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.asynclocal-1?view=net-7.0) to store some *ambient data that is local to a given asynchronous control flow*, but what would I use in python to get a similar functionality?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html?highlight=contextvars#asyncio-support Each async Task creates its own context.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I've implemented it and it works the same way as in C#. Thanks!